# How to make a GUI on Xcode (iPhone) for a console application made in C.

Tags: iphone, xcode, terminal

I have a console application made in C that works great in Terminal. But I need to port it to iPhone. So I need to make an GUI that respond imitating a Terminal. So basically I need to input data and get the output (printf's) from the console application. This C application makes a connection to a Router so Im not sure if theres a way to implement a GUI maybe a textfield that recieves output from the console app. The thing is, iphone doesnt have terminal, the C app compiles good in Xcode and it gets loaded to the iPhone too. But sinces there is no terminal.. it just prints some stuff like "Connecting.." but after connection is done... it disconnects. I guess because it doesnt find any terminal to interact with. I've tried -MobileTerminal- but that app only runs on jailbroken iphones so I dont want that.

Any suggestions ??

Comment: Redirect stdin/stdio programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, create an iPhone app. Create your UI and other things accordingly.

Second, add a C file to your project, do your logic there. Since main() is not the entry point for your app, you need to get your code logic modified and organized into methods.

Third, add the reference to the C file you created in the place where you wanna use the logic.

Last, call the method directly and that's about it.

---

Here is a little example I tried:

1. I created an iPhone single view project getCNumber.
2. I added two files to the project: Number.h and Number.m

in Number.h:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int getNum();
```

in Number.m:

```
  #include "Number.h"

  int getNum()
  {
      return 234;
  }


3. In getCNumber.xib, I have a label.
```

In getCNumber.h,

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface getCNumber : UIViewController
    {
         UILabel *lblNum;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lblNum;

    @end
```

in getCNumber.m, in -(void)viewDidLoad(),

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
          [super viewDidLoad];
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

          int someNum = getNum();
          self.lblNum.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number from C: %i",someNum];

    }
```

You might need to do some extra work to get your C program going with the iOS "wrapper", as I don't know exactly what you did in your C, but this should show you the general idea here.

Hope it helps.